# SQL Constraint Prevent Book From Being Loaned Twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints

I am writing a Library database and have the following tables:

Copy (copies of books)

```
Id int
ISBN nvarchar(13)
Purchase_Date datetime
```

Customer

```
Id int
First_Name nvarchar(255)
Last_Name nvarchar(255)
Address nvarchar(255)
Membership_Joined_Date datetime
Membership_Expiry_Date datetime
```

Loan

```
Id int
CopyId int
CustomerId int
Loan_Date datetime
Loan_Expiry_Date datetime
Extension_Date datetime (nullable)
Return_Date datetime (nullable)
```

The copyId and customerId fields are foreign keys from the Copy and Customer tables respectively.

Is there an expression I can write against the loans table that would prevent me from loaning the same book twice? I use a null `Return_Date` in the Loan table to check if a book is already loaned out. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases (including SQL Server) support filtered indexes.  You can create a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_loan_copyid
    on loan(copyid) where Loan_Expiry_Date is null;
```